# is there a way for web apps to access biometrics for biometrics login without the use of passkey

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly, biometrics, browser-api

Is there a way to use phone biometrics such as faceID/fingerprint on android and Iphone on Blazor webassembly .net6 PWA to function it the same way it is in native apps without the use of passkey.

I have tried the WebAuthn but it keep asking the passkey instead of just biometrics which some of the demo webpage has shown (1), in the first image of the second step. Is this the only way for web applications such as blazor webassembly to access it or is there any other way?

(1) https://developers.google.com/codelabs/webauthn-reauth#2

Comment: Not sure if you ever found what you were looking for, but you could take a look at https://webauthn.io/